# how to jump between dialog without confusion on watson assistant(conversation)?

Tags: watson-conversation

There're 3 main nodes in our watson conversation(assistant) dialog, we'd like to ask question between each nodes and each of them have a long child nodes, how can we keep the previous answer while we jump to ask another question ?for example, A qustion like: I'd like to book a flight, Answer: what'd date is your flight? Then Ask: My car is out of oder, Answer would be: please get to a repair store, now I will keep answering that flight date, a complex dialog diagram as the attached, any advice would be appreciated... another example as follows: ask a question on node1(not finished yet), ask another question on node2(finished), then keep answering question on node1 [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can gather multiple pieces of information from a user within the same node as an alternative to create child nodes usings **SLOTS**. Slots collect information at the users' pace. Details the user provides upfront are saved, and the service asks only for the details they do not.
More details here: https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/conversation/dialog-slots.html#dialog-slots

Also,you can **Digress** from the main topic by switching it ON

[image]

More details on Digressions: https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/conversation/tutorial-digressions.html#tutorial-digressions